# inno to wix upgrade

Tags: wix

I have wix installer with latest version.Now i want to upgrade the latest wix with old inno set up.(inno to inno upgrade working fine And wix to wix upgrade also working fine.)Please suggest me a way to put upgrade code in latest wix

Answer (score 5):

As inno setup doesnt create a windows installer file you wont be able to use the upgrade product feature in windows installer. What you could do however is to write a custom action that runs a shell command that uninstalls the old inno setup before installation.